# Hi, I need too have a dropdown on my nevigation bar but he doesn't want to drop down,

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I need too have a dropdown on my nevigation bar but he doesn't want to drop down, I saw someone change on the : href ="#" changed that for  href="/posts" and it worked for him but not for me, I'm using bootstrap 4.4.1 if it helps. Thank you all.

> ```
>     <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
> ```
>
> aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#my-target">
>             Dropdown
>           
>           
>             Action
>             Another action
>             
>             Something else here

Answer (score 0):

```
Maybe try something like this..
<style>
<!-- CSS -->
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
</style>
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_dropdown&stacked=h) for bootstrap 4 NavBar with dropdown.